# If Project.find(8).users works in my Rails Console, how do I get it to work inside my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So when I do `Project.find(8).users` it returns all the users associated with that project..in the console.

However, when I do:

`<%= current_user.projects.Users.count %>` it gives me an error.

How do I make the transition from Rails Console to the actual app, in terms of the syntax here?

Comment: How are projects and users related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
current_user.projects.sum { |p| p.users.count - 1 }
```

This will return the total number of users associated with projects that the user is associated with, minus'ing 1 per-project to remove the current user.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find) returns a record that you can access the users assocation with. But you cannot do this with a [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) association because the accessor that is created returns an array.

```
Project.find(8)       # => #<Project>
current_user.projects # => [#<Project>]
```

You have to choose a single project in the array returned or use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) to get all the users of each project.

Comment: I hear you lecturing from on high, but this answer is not much useful to me. Especially given that I have worked through this solution with someone more patient....this answer really falls short.

Answer (score 1):

A simple call inside your controller as you were doing it should work. But I would just write:

```
          @users =  Project.find(8).users
```

and in your view you can use @users as you like.For example

```
<p><%= pluralize(<@users.size,'user')%> Found<p>
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>Name</th>   
       <th>Surname</th>
       <th>Username</th>
   </tr>
   <% @users.each do |user|%>     
   <tr>
      <td><%= user.name%></td>
      <td><%= user.surname%></td>    
      <td><%= user.username%></td>   
   </tr>
   <%end%>  
</table>
```

Make sure you have a has_may relationship defined in your project model.

** I got use to use size with my arrays...but count does it too :)

Comment: Thanks for this...makes total sense. Forgot that I could simply create an instance variable and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I should add, for posterity, that if you're using a HABTM join table and want to do this sort of work, you should really use SQL. Something like:

```
User.find_by_sql "SELECT count(*) from projects_users WHERE user_id != #{current_user.id} AND project_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id from projects_users WHERE user_id = #{current_user.id})"
```

Even better would be to make this query a method in your model, rather than have it cluttering up your controller.

Answer (score -2):

For those interested in the answer, I had to do the following:

```
<%= current_user.projects.inject(0){|sum,p| sum+= (p.users.count-1); sum} %>
```

Which returns the number of users associated with the current project, less the currently logged in user.